# How to Create Table in Stack Overflow Answers & Questions?

Tags: support, markdown, markdown-rendering

Why, despite support of [markdown](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) in the stack overflow, Still I can not be through this language or **HTML** making a table?

[Standard Markdown](http://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/syntax#html) should have allowed in-lined HTML table.

How can I making Tables like this in Stack overflow questions and answers ?

[image: rendered table]