# Introduce Tables to the main page

Tags: discussion, feature-request, markdown

Since we have documentation, we have a new [markdown for tables](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#tables). This is a documented feature.

Why not have the same option for the main site? Or Meta?

Related (But now turning into a Feature Request, that is actualy implemented at Documentation):

- [How to create table in SO Question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/277716/how-to-create-table-in-so-question)
- [How to Create Table in Stack Overflow Answers & Questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/296271/how-to-create-table-in-stack-overflow-answers-questions)
- [How to put tables in Stack Overflow?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/302471/how-to-put-tables-in-stack-overflow)

So what is the reason, we have a markdown, that support this feature, but only on Documentation? Why not introduce this feature to the main page?

I remember, that sometimes I need a table.